# Is it possible to express the indicator function for a real interval in terms of other function/s?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Suppose that I've an indicator function defined for an interval in $\mathbb R$, i.e., suppose that $f(x)=1$ if $x\in(a,b)$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then can I express $f$ without using indicator functions? That is, is it possible to define $f$ using only $a$ or $b$ or any other "simple" function? Note that I'm not emphasizing that the interval is open-any interval in $\mathbb R$ should behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least almost everywhere. It's pretty common to do

> $$1_{(a,b)}={1\over 2}\big(\operatorname{sgn}(x-a)-\operatorname{sgn}(x-b)\big)$$

The equal sign is sort of a lie, but we'll get to that. When $a<x<b$ we have $\operatorname{sgn}(x-b)=-1, \operatorname{sgn}(x-a)=+1$ so that the combination is $1$. When $x<a<b$ or $a<b<x$ then both signs are the same, hence we get $0$. The endpoints are a little finnicky, for $x=a$ we get $-{1\over 2}$ and for $x=b$ we get ${1\over 2}$, but this is only a minor inconvenience.

If you want a strict equality, you can modify for the endpoints easily using $\delta$ functions. So for the open interval you'd do

$$1_{(a,b)}={1\over 2}\big(\operatorname{sgn}(x-a)-\delta(a)-\operatorname{sgn}(x-b)-\delta(b)\big)$$

For a closed interval you'd do

$$1_{[a,b]}={1\over 2}\big(\operatorname{sgn}(x-a)+\delta(a)-\operatorname{sgn}(x-b)+\delta(b)\big)$$

and so on for half-open intervals.